# Undefined view in blade for Laravel

Tags: laravel, undefined-variable

I am facing an issue with an undefined variable in a blade view for my Laravel project.

I believe I have defined everything correctly

This is the line in the blade view which is causing my issue.

```
<a href="{{action('RollController@paid', $record->id)}}" title="Paid" class="btn btn-success"><i class="material-icons">done</i></a>
```

It is complaining about the record variable

This is the public function in the RollController

```
public function paid($id)
{

    $record = Roll::find($id);

    if ($record!= null)
 {
     $record->status = 'C';
     $record->save();

     return redirect(action('RollController@index'))->with ('success', 'Member Paid');
 }

 return redirect(action('RollController@index'));

}
```

This is the Web Routing

```
Route::get('/roll/paid/{id}', 'RollController@paid')->middleware('auth');
```

Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: where is the code you have to send $record variable in blade?

Comment: This code isn't returning a view, which means it's never using a blade template.  Can you please paste the code for the index method so we can debug?

Answer (score 2):

The error is because you are trying to access a variable i.e. `$record->id` on your view which doesn't exist, look into this:

```
return redirect(action('RollController@index'))->with ('success', 'Member Paid');
return redirect(action('RollController@index'));
```

in both the cases you are not passing the variable that contains the value in it. So try this:

```
return redirect(action('RollController@index'))->with('record', $record);
```

and also change the anchor tag from:

```
href="{{action('RollController@paid', $record->id)}}"
```

to

```
href="{{route('paid',['id' => $record->id])}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

href shouldn't have the controller name and/or method. You put the route in the href attribute. So change

```
href="{{action('RollController@paid', $record->id)}}"
```

into

```
href="{{route('paid',['id' => $record->id])}}"
```

Also change your web.php.

```
Route::get('/roll/paid/{id}', 'RollController@paid')->middleware('auth')->name('paid');
```

What I did was, I added a name to the route in web.php by adding `name('paid')`. You can add any name you want. Then I used this named route in href attribute.